# DB Query retrieval of large data set

Tags: database, perl, jdbc

When we use JDBC (Java) or DBD (Perl) and fire a query, we get results.

Now in my program, I just write the results to a file.

The data set is huge (millions of rows).

Is there any way to reduce the memory footprint.

What I observed in Perl is that it does not release the memory used for binding the data to the variables.

## Pseudocode

#### Perl

1) Establish Connection. Execute Query

```
my $data ;

while ( $dbh->next )
{

    # Bind variables ;

    $data = ..

    writeToFile ( data  =>  $ data ) ;

}
```

#### Java

In JDBC, if I set the bound data variables/objects to null, would it release memory while performing garbage collection

1) Establish connection

```
while ( results->hasNext() )
{

    Data data ;      

    writeToFile ( data ) ;

    data = null ;
}
```

PERL DBD Driver.

```
I have not installed any special driver. Whatever was installed by unix admin with perl module.
```

JDBC Driver.

```
Standard sybase driver.
```

Comment: I see no clear question, please clarify what it is you want to know. Note that exact behavior is not generic for JDBC and depends on the driver implementation. If you want to have any chance of an answer, you need to specify which driver you are using.

Comment: The behaviour of Perl's DBI also depends on the design of the driver. You must specify which DBD module you are using -- i.e. what sort of database is this. In general, drivers will reuse the data space for subsequent fetch operations, so a first guess would be to retrieve your data in chunks of, say, 100 rows using the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` options

Comment: I will look into the limit option in jdbc. For perl , i will check if there is such option.

Comment: Which DBD are you using?  Show the first parameter to DBI->connect

Comment: my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Sybase:', $user, $passwd);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to reduce the memory footprint

There could be, at least for JDBC; it would depend on the implementation of the JDBC driver. For example, the default behavior for MySQL Connector/J is to retrieve the entire ResultSet immediately. However, you can tell the JDBC connection to "stream" the results by specifying `setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` for the `Statement` object.